# Given a simple pole, find the difference of two Laurents series expansion coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that f is analytic on the annulus $\{z \in \mathbb C:1/2<|z|<2\}$ except for the simple pole at 1. Suppose that the residue of $f$ at $z = 1$ is $1$. Let $\sum_na_nz^{n}$ and $\sum_nb_nz^{n}$be the Laurent expansion of $f$ on the annuli ${z : 1/2 < |z| < 1}$ and ${z : 1 < |z| < 2}$, respectively. Compute $b_n − a_n$ for every integer n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* $g(z) = f(z) - \frac1{z-1}$ has a removable singularity at $z=1$.
It can be continued to an analytic function on the annulus
$\{z \in \mathbb C:1/2<|z|<2\}$ with a Laurent expansion
$$
 g(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n z^{n} 
$$
valid for $1/2 < |z| < 2$.

Now compute the Laurent expansion of $g$ in $ \{z : 1/2 < |z| < 1\}$ and $\{z : 1 < |z| < 2\}$, respectively, using the given Laurent expansions
of $f$ in those annuli, and the geometric series
for $|z| < 1$ and $|z| > 1$, respectively.

Then use that the coefficients of the Laurent expansion are unique,
to get a relationship between $a_n$, $b_n$ and $c_n$.

Spoiler:

> For $n \ge 0$: $c_n = a_n + 1 = b_n$. For $n < 0$: $c_n = a_n = b_n - 1$.

Comment: Do you want f-1/（z-1）instead？

Comment: @Keith: Oops, you are right! I hope that it is correct now.

Comment: I see, thank you very much!

Comment: yes，so sorry that I forgot to accept it. Thank u so much！